# How do i include my static assets in webpack and use them in angular2 app?

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, assets, webpack-dev-server

I have separate files for production and development environments of my app, my dev environment works fine, I am not getting how to i use my static assets in the webpack and use them in the app, they being directly accessed in my html and css files as shown below

authentication.component.html

```
<img src="/assets/images/myimage.png" />
```

authentication.component.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "untitled-font-5";
  src:url("/assets/fonts/untitled-font-5.eot");
  src:url("/assets/fonts/untitled-font-5.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("/assets/fonts/untitled-font-5.woff") format("woff"),
    url("/assets/fonts/untitled-font-5.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("/assets/fonts/untitled-font-5.svg#untitled-font-5") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

}
```

This is my project's directory structure

[image]

and my webpack config files

common

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/app/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({   
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })
  ]
};
```

dev

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  }
});
```

prod

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },

  htmlLoader: {
    minimize: false // workaround for ng2
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
      mangle: {
        keep_fnames: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    })
  ]
});
```